# Javascript Date Picker Issues in IE10

Tags: javascript

Similar to this thread:

[JavaScript Datepicker issue in IE11 - crossobj.visibility="hidden";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434491/javascript-datepicker-issue-in-ie11-crossobj-visibility-hidden)

I'm stuck with having to use an outdated popcalendar.js, which does not work correctly in IE10.  Once a date is picked, it puts "115" into the calendar input, where FF and Chrome put "2015".

I've been trying to come up with a solution, as it likely has something to do with how "ie" and/or "ns" is set within the code, but I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Code as follows:

```
//  written by Tan Ling Wee on 2 December 2001
```

//  email : fuushikaden@yahoo.com

```
var bPageLoaded=false
    var ie=document.all
    var dom=document.getElementById
    var ns4=document.layers
    var crossobj, crossMonthObj, crossYearObj
    var monthSelected, yearSelected, dateSelected
    var omonthSelected, oyearSelected, odateSelected
    var monthConstructed
    var yearConstructed
    var intervalID1, intervalID2
    var timeoutID1, timeoutID2
    var ctlToPlaceValue
    var ctlNow
    var dateFormat
    var today = new Date()
    var dateNow  = today.getDate()
    var monthNow = today.getMonth()
    var yearNow  = today.getYear()
    var nStartingYear

    if (dom)
    {
        document.write ("<div id='calendar' style='position:absolute;visibility:hidden;'><table width=220 style='font-family:arial; font-size:11px; border-width:1; border-style:solid;border-color:#a0a0a0;font-family:arial; font-size:11px}' bgcolor='#ffffff'><tr bgcolor='#333366'><td><table width='218'><tr><td style='padding:2px;font-family:arial; font-size:11px;'><font color='#ffffff'><B><span id='caption'></span></B></font></td><td align=right><a href='javascript:hideCalendar()'><IMG SRC='/mortracstatic/images/registration/close.gif' WIDTH='15' HEIGHT='13' BORDER='0' ALT='Close the Calendar'></a></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td style='padding:5px' bgcolor=#ffffff><span id='content'></span></td></tr><tr bgcolor=#f0f0f0><td style='padding:5px' align=center><span id='lblToday'></span></td></tr></table></div><div id='selectMonth' style='position:absolute;visibility:hidden;'></div><div id='selectYear'  style='position:absolute;visibility:hidden;'></div>");
    }

    var monthName = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

    var dayName = new Array ("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")

    var styleAnchor="text-decoration:none;color:black;"
    var styleLightBorder="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#a0a0a0}"

    var imgsrc = new Array("/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop1.gif","/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop2.gif","/mortracstatic/images/registration/left1.gif","/mortracstatic/images/registration/left2.gif","/mortracstatic/images/registration/right1.gif","/mortracstatic/images/registration/right2.gif");
    var img = new Array();

    function swapImage(srcImg, destImg){
        if (ie) { document.getElementById(srcImg).setAttribute("src",destImg) }
    }

    function init() {

        if (!ns4)
        {
            for (i=0;i<imgsrc.length;i++)
            {
                img[i] = new Image
                img[i].src=imgsrc[i]
            }

            if (!ie) {
                yearNow += 1900
            }

            crossobj=(dom)?document.getElementById("calendar").style : ie? document.all.calendar : document.calendar
            hideCalendar()

            crossMonthObj=(dom)?document.getElementById("selectMonth").style : ie? document.all.selectMonth : document.selectMonth

            crossYearObj=(dom)?document.getElementById("selectYear").style : ie? document.all.selectYear : document.selectYear

            monthConstructed=false;
            yearConstructed=false;

            document.getElementById("lblToday").innerHTML = "Today is <a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:monthSelected=monthNow;yearSelected=yearNow;constructCalendar();'>"+dayName[today.getDay()]+", " + dateNow + " " + monthName[monthNow].substring(0,3) + " " + yearNow + "</a>"   

            // decrease by one month

            sHTML1="<span id='spanLeft' style='border-style:solid;border-width:1;border-color:#9D9DCE;cursor:pointer' onmouseover='swapImage(\"changeLeft\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/left2.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#ddddee\"' onclick='javascript:decMonth()' onmouseout='clearInterval(intervalID1);swapImage(\"changeLeft\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/left1.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onmousedown='clearTimeout(timeoutID1);timeoutID1=setTimeout(\"StartDecMonth()\",500)' onmouseup='clearTimeout(timeoutID1);clearInterval(intervalID1)'>&nbsp<IMG id='changeLeft' SRC='/mortracstatic/images/registration/left1.gif' BORDER=0>&nbsp</span>&nbsp;"

            // increase by one month

            sHTML1+="<span id='spanRight' style='border-style:solid;border-width:1;border-color:#9d9dce;cursor:pointer' onmouseover='swapImage(\"changeRight\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/right2.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#ddddee\"' onmouseout='clearInterval(intervalID1);swapImage(\"changeRight\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/right1.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#9d9dce\"'  onclick='incMonth()' onmousedown='clearTimeout(timeoutID1);timeoutID1=setTimeout(\"StartIncMonth()\",500)' onmouseup='clearTimeout(timeoutID1);clearInterval(intervalID1)'>&nbsp<IMG id='changeRight' SRC='/mortracstatic/images/registration/right1.gif' BORDER=0>&nbsp</span>&nbsp"

            // month pulldown

            sHTML1+="<span id='spanMonth' style='border-style:solid;border-width:1;border-color:#9d9dce;cursor:pointer' onmouseover='swapImage(\"changeMonth\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop2.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#ddddee\"' onmouseout='swapImage(\"changeMonth\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop1.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onclick='popUpMonth()'></span>&nbsp;"

            // year pulldown

            sHTML1+="<span id='spanYear' style='border-style:solid;border-width:1;border-color:#9d9dce;cursor:pointer' onmouseover='swapImage(\"changeYear\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop2.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#ddddee\"' onmouseout='swapImage(\"changeYear\",\"/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop1.gif\");this.style.borderColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onclick='popUpYear()'></span>&nbsp;"

            document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML  = sHTML1

            bPageLoaded=true
        }
    }

    function hideCalendar() {
        crossobj.visibility="hidden"
        if (crossMonthObj != null){crossMonthObj.visibility="hidden"}
        if (crossYearObj != null){crossYearObj.visibility="hidden"}
    }

    function closeCalendar() {
        var sTmp

        var paddedMonth = (monthSelected+1)
        if ((monthSelected+1) < 10)
        {
            paddedMonth = "0" + (monthSelected+1)
        }

        var paddedDay = dateSelected
        if (dateSelected < 10)
        {
            paddedDay = "0" + dateSelected
        }

        hideCalendar();
        sTmp = dateFormat
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("mmm","<n>")
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("mm","<m>")
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("<n>",monthName[monthSelected])
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("<m>",paddedMonth)
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("m",monthSelected+1)
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("dd",paddedDay)
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace ("d",dateSelected)

        ctlToPlaceValue.value = dateFormat.replace ("yyyy",yearSelected)
        if ( ctlToPlaceValue.onchange != null ) {
            ctlToPlaceValue.onchange();
        }
    }

    /*** Month Pulldown ***/

    function StartDecMonth()
    {
        intervalID1=setInterval("decMonth()",80)
    }

    function StartIncMonth()
    {
        intervalID1=setInterval("incMonth()",80)
    }

    function incMonth () {
        monthSelected++
        if (monthSelected>11) {
            monthSelected=0
            yearSelected++
        }
        constructCalendar()
    }

    function decMonth () {
        monthSelected--
        if (monthSelected<0) {
            monthSelected=11
            yearSelected--
        }
        constructCalendar()
    }

    function constructMonth() {
        popDownYear()
        if (!monthConstructed) {
            sHTML = ""
            for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
                sName = monthName[i];
                if (i==monthSelected){
                    sName = "<B>" + sName + "</B>"
                }
                sHTML += "<tr><td id='m" + i + "' onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundColor=\"\"' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='monthConstructed=false;monthSelected=" + i + ";constructCalendar();popDownMonth();event.cancelBubble=true'>&nbsp;" + sName + "&nbsp;</td></tr>"
            }

            document.getElementById("selectMonth").innerHTML = "<table width=70 style='font-family:arial; font-size:11px; border-width:1; border-style:solid; border-color:#a0a0a0;' bgcolor='#f0f0f0' cellspacing=0 onmouseover='clearTimeout(timeoutID1)' onmouseout='clearTimeout(timeoutID1);timeoutID1=setTimeout(\"popDownMonth()\",100);event.cancelBubble=true'>" + sHTML + "</table>"

            monthConstructed=true
        }
    }

    function popUpMonth() {
        constructMonth()
        crossMonthObj.visibility = (dom||ie)? "visible" : "show"
        crossMonthObj.left = parseInt(crossobj.left) + 50
        crossMonthObj.top = parseInt(crossobj.top) + 26
    }

    function popDownMonth() {
        crossMonthObj.visibility= "hidden"
    }

    /*** Year Pulldown ***/

    function incYear() {
        for (i=0; i<7; i++){
            newYear = (i+nStartingYear)+1
            if (newYear==yearSelected)
            { txtYear = "&nbsp;<B>" + newYear + "</B>&nbsp;" }
            else
            { txtYear = "&nbsp;" + newYear + "&nbsp;" }
            document.getElementById("y"+i).innerHTML = txtYear
        }
        nStartingYear ++;
    }

    function decYear() {
        for (i=0; i<7; i++){
            newYear = (i+nStartingYear)-1
            if (newYear==yearSelected)
            { txtYear = "&nbsp;<B>" + newYear + "</B>&nbsp;" }
            else
            { txtYear = "&nbsp;" + newYear + "&nbsp;" }
            document.getElementById("y"+i).innerHTML = txtYear
        }
        nStartingYear --;
    }

    function selectYear(nYear) {
        yearSelected=parseInt(nYear+nStartingYear);
        yearConstructed=false;
        constructCalendar();
        popDownYear();
    }

    function constructYear() {
        popDownMonth()
        sHTML = ""
        if (!yearConstructed) {

            sHTML = "<tr><td align='center' onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onmouseout='clearInterval(intervalID1);this.style.backgroundColor=\"\"' style='cursor:pointer' onmousedown='clearInterval(intervalID1);intervalID1=setInterval(\"decYear()\",30)' onmouseup='clearInterval(intervalID1)'>-</td></tr>"

            j = 0
            nStartingYear = yearSelected-3
            for (i=(yearSelected-3); i<=(yearSelected+3); i++) {
                sName = i;
                if (i==yearSelected){
                    sName = "<B>" + sName + "</B>"
                }
                sHTML += "<tr><td id='y" + j + "' onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundColor=\"\"' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='selectYear("+j+");event.cancelBubble=true'>&nbsp;" + sName + "&nbsp;</td></tr>"
                j ++;
            }

            sHTML += "<tr><td align='center' onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#9d9dce\"' onmouseout='clearInterval(intervalID2);this.style.backgroundColor=\"\"' style='cursor:pointer' onmousedown='clearInterval(intervalID2);intervalID2=setInterval(\"incYear()\",30)' onmouseup='clearInterval(intervalID2)'>+</td></tr>"

            document.getElementById("selectYear").innerHTML = "<table width=44 style='font-family:arial; font-size:11px; border-width:1; border-style:solid; border-color:#a0a0a0;' bgcolor='#f0f0f0' onmouseover='clearTimeout(timeoutID2)' onmouseout='clearTimeout(timeoutID2);timeoutID2=setTimeout(\"popDownYear()\",100)' cellspacing=0>" + sHTML + "</table>"

            yearConstructed = true
        }
    }

    function popDownYear() {
        clearInterval(intervalID1)
        clearTimeout(timeoutID1)
        clearInterval(intervalID2)
        clearTimeout(timeoutID2)
        crossYearObj.visibility= "hidden"
    }

    function popUpYear() {
        var leftOffset

        constructYear()
        crossYearObj.visibility = (dom||ie)? "visible" : "show"
        leftOffset = parseInt(crossobj.left) + document.getElementById("spanYear").offsetLeft 
        if (ie)
        {
            leftOffset += 6
        }
        crossYearObj.left = leftOffset
        crossYearObj.top = parseInt(crossobj.top) + 26
    }

    /*** calendar ***/

    function constructCalendar () {
        var startDate = new Date (yearSelected,monthSelected,1)
        var endDate = new Date (yearSelected,monthSelected+1,1);
        endDate = new Date (endDate - (24*60*60*1000));
        numDaysInMonth = endDate.getDate()

        datePointer = 0
        dayPointer = startDate.getDay()

        sHTML = "<table style='font-family:verdana; font-size:10px;'><tr>"

        for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
            sHTML += "<td width='27' align='right'><B>"+ dayName[i]+"</B></td>"
        }
        sHTML +="</tr>"

        for ( var i=1 ; i<=dayPointer ; i++ )
        {
            sHTML += "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
        }

        for ( datePointer=1 ; datePointer<=numDaysInMonth; datePointer++ )
        {
            dayPointer++;
            sHTML += "<td align=right>"
            if ((datePointer==odateSelected) && (monthSelected==omonthSelected) && (yearSelected==oyearSelected))
            {
                if ((datePointer==dateNow)&&(monthSelected==monthNow)&&(yearSelected==yearNow))
                {
                    sHTML += "<b><a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:dateSelected="+datePointer + ";closeCalendar();'><font color=#990000>&nbsp;" + datePointer + "</font>&nbsp;</a></b>"
                }
                else if (dayPointer % 7 == 1 )
                {
                    sHTML += "<font color=#909090><a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:dateSelected="+datePointer + ";closeCalendar();'>&nbsp;" + datePointer + "&nbsp;</a>"
                }
                else
                {
                    sHTML += "<a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:dateSelected="+datePointer + ";closeCalendar();'>&nbsp;" + datePointer + "&nbsp;</a>"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((datePointer==dateNow)&&(monthSelected==monthNow)&&(yearSelected==yearNow))
                {
                    sHTML += "<b><a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:dateSelected="+datePointer + ";closeCalendar();'><font color=#990000>&nbsp;" + datePointer + "</font>&nbsp;</a></b>"
                }
                else if (dayPointer % 7 == 1 )
                {
                    sHTML += "<font color=#909090><a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:dateSelected="+datePointer + ";closeCalendar();'>&nbsp;" + datePointer + "&nbsp;</a>"
                }
                else
                {
                    sHTML += "<a style='"+styleAnchor+"' href='javascript:dateSelected="+datePointer + ";closeCalendar();'>&nbsp;" + datePointer + "&nbsp;</a>"
                }
            }


            sHTML += ""
            if (dayPointer % 7 == 0)
            {
                sHTML += "</tr><tr>"
            }
            sHTML += "</td>"
        }

        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML   = sHTML
        document.getElementById("spanMonth").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + monthName[monthSelected] + "&nbsp;<IMG id='changeMonth' SRC='/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop1.gif' WIDTH='12' HEIGHT='10' BORDER=0>"
        document.getElementById("spanYear").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + yearSelected + "&nbsp;<IMG id='changeYear' SRC='/mortracstatic/images/registration/drop1.gif' WIDTH='12' HEIGHT='10' BORDER=0>"
    }

    function popUpCalendar(ctl, ctl2, format) {

        var leftpos=0
        var toppos=0

        if (bPageLoaded)
        {
            if ( crossobj.visibility == "hidden" ) {
                ctlToPlaceValue = ctl2
                dateFormat=format;

                formatChar = " "
                aFormat = dateFormat.split(formatChar)
                if (aFormat.length<3)
                {
                    formatChar = "/"
                    aFormat = dateFormat.split(formatChar)
                    if (aFormat.length<3)
                    {
                        formatChar = "-"
                        aFormat = dateFormat.split(formatChar)
                        if (aFormat.length<3)
                        {
                            // invalid date format
                            formatChar=""
                        }
                    }           
                }

                tokensChanged = 0
                if ( formatChar != "" )
                {
                    // use user's date
                    aData = ctl2.value.split(formatChar)
                    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
                    {
                        if (aFormat[i]=="d")
                        {
                            dateSelected = parseInt(aData[i])
                            tokensChanged ++
                        }
                        else if (aFormat[i]=="m")
                        {
                            monthSelected = parseInt(aData[i]) - 1
                            tokensChanged ++
                        }
                        else if (aFormat[i]=="yyyy")
                        {
                            yearSelected = parseInt(aData[i])
                            tokensChanged ++
                        }
                        else if (aFormat[i]=="mmm")
                        {
                            for (j=0; j<12; j++)
                            {   
                                if (aData[i]==monthName[j])
                                {
                                    monthSelected=j
                                    tokensChanged ++
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ((tokensChanged!=3)||isNaN(dateSelected)||isNaN(monthSelected)||isNaN(yearSelected))
                {
                    dateSelected = dateNow
                    monthSelected = monthNow
                    yearSelected = yearNow
                }

                odateSelected=dateSelected
                omonthSelected=monthSelected
                oyearSelected=yearSelected

                aTag = ctl
                do {
                    aTag = aTag.offsetParent;
                    leftpos += aTag.offsetLeft;
                    toppos += aTag.offsetTop;
                } while(aTag.tagName!="BODY");

                crossobj.left = ctl.offsetLeft + leftpos
                crossobj.top = ctl.offsetTop + toppos + ctl.offsetHeight + 2
                constructCalendar (1, monthSelected, yearSelected);
                crossobj.visibility=(dom||ie)? "visible" : "show"
            }
            else
            {
                hideCalendar()
                if (ctlNow!=ctl) {
                    popUpCalendar(ctl, ctl2, format)
                }
            }
            ctlNow = ctl
        }
    }

window.onload=init
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fairly awful code that should be rewritten, however you can patch it. Your problem is here:

```
if (!ie) {
  yearNow += 1900
}
```

use:

```
if (yearNow < 1000) {
  yearNow += 1900
}
```

It stems from the use of *getYear* rather than *getFullYear*:

```
var yearNow  = today.getYear()
```

but I'm not sure what effect changing to *getFullYear* will have on other code. 
An alternative is to add the following;

```
var ie=document.all
var dom=document.getElementById
var ns4=document.layers

// Add this:
var undefined;
if (dom) ie = ns4 = undefined;
```

Untested of course. ;-)

It may also have issues across daylight saving boundaries where it will skip a day one way or the other because of:

```
   endDate = new Date (endDate - (24*60*60*1000));
```

Test and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you Rob!  It looks like your first suggestion did the trick.  Testing looks good so far!

Comment: Just don't expect dates before 1000 to work correctly. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that calendar doesn't use "let" and "const" javascript keywords that are not supported by IE10.